# Conversion from NSString to Hex

Tags: objective-c

i am new in this field and i was working on a conversion of NSString to Hex and have been stuck into it. My String lets suppose is 1,FF,F8 now how can i convert that into hex numbers like 0x01,0x0FF and 0x0F8

Comment: You need to give more detail and show what you've tried and why it doesn't work. Without this people trying to help you are only guessing. For example, what to you mean by "into hex numbers"; you could mean produce text strings which look like hex literals or interpreting the text you have as a list of numbers represented in hex (numbers stored in a program are not "hex", but textual representations of them can be). So add the detail and what you've tried and someone might be able to help you along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step would be to split the string containing "1,FF,F8" into three strings containing the separate hex values, "1", "FF", "F8".

```
NSString *hexString = @"1,FF,F8";
NSArray *hexValues = [hexString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

As for the conversion from NSString to hex, I'm not quite sure what exactly you want.

If you just want to add on a "0x0" to the beginning of the hex values, you can just do:

```
NSMutableArray *formattedHexValues = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSString *hexValue in hexValues) {
    [formattedHexValues addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x0%@", hexValue]];
}
```

If you want to actually get the integer value of the hex string, do this:

```
for(NSString *hexString in formattedHexValues) {
    unsigned int value;
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString] scanHexInt:&value];
    NSLog(@"The value is %d", value);
}
```

Typed this out in the browser so there might be a syntax mistake or two, but it generally should work fine.